# Looking for a way to "emulate" full websites (incl. requests, history, URLs) as javascript examples within another page?

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks, emulation

I'm working on a website that displays html/css/javascript code examples. Something like a best practices library.

Examples could look like this:

- How to implement full clickable teaser elements
- How a good heading outline should look like
- How keyboard focus should be managed in modal dialogs

I'm using CodePen.io to create the examples, so users can try them out and play with them to their wishes.

Every example is presented on a single webpage, and every example should be written only in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (the things that CodePen.io provides).

The only problem there is: how can I emulate (fake?) requests?

- For example, one of the examples will show how clicking on a button fires an AJAX call to a server, then displays an info somewhere on the page. In the background, it's not really an AJAX call, it's only a "fake" AJAX call that's handled by some JavaScript.
- Another example is navigating between pages: the URL should change (e.g. `examples/123/#index`, then after clicking a link it's `examples/123/#some-other-page`), but in fact, it's still the same page that's displayed again and again, but depending on the URL, some different content is displayed. Browser history needs to be working, too.
- One last example could be submitting a form and displaying input errors inline in the form: how can I get the POST data in an easy, and display the form again with errors?

This could surely be done using plain JavaScript. But I'm sure there are libraries for doing stuff like that, I just don't know what to search for.

In fact, what I'm describing are mini 1-page-applications. But I don't need a fully fledged framework like AngularJS, something very simple that can handle requests (incl. managing browser history and URLs) is enough for my purposes, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

to create a fake server to do AJAX request, you can use this nodejs module for example:

http://www.begeek.fr/starcraft-remastered-lannonce-surprise-de-blizzard-lete-235328?utm_source=facebook&utm_campaign=begeek

With this module you can doing real GET, POST, PUT or DELETE request and send fake data to your javascript application.

An other way is simply use a timeout and a Promise to fake an AJAX request who send mocked data. But with this method you're never send a real HTTP request, it's simply functions who return data.

Here is an example of a function who create a Promise to fake a server response:

```
function sendFakeUser() {
    let user = {
        name: 'antoine',
        email: 'a@antoine.fr'
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(user);
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

you can call this function like this:

```
sendFakeUser()
    .then((user) => {
        console.info(user);
        // console or do stuff with your data
    }
```